# Many-to-many relations in DB design and deduplication

Tags: sql, database, ddl

I have two M:M tables: `countries (id,..)` and `neighbor_countries(origin_country_id, neighbor_country_id,...)`

Is there a way to deduplicate `origin_country_id` and `neighbor_country_id` combinations? For example, `USA=>Mexico` is essentially the same as `Mexico=>USA`...

I could add logic to my code to check for both permutations. I was wondering if there's any elegant solution in SQL to do it in a single query.

How would you go about it? How to check in a single query if USA and Mexico are neighboring countries?

PS: Apologies for the unhelpful title, I didn't know how to frame this question properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with multiple conditions in a where

```
SELECT "Yes" 
FROM countries l 
JOIN neighbor_countries ON l.id = origin_country_id
JOIN countries r ON r.id = neighbor_country_id
WHERE (l.name = "USA" AND r.name = "Mexico") OR (l.name = "Mexico" AND r.name = "USA")
```